# Installing/updating R 3.6 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, repository, r

I've recently acquired a machine with Ubuntu 18.04 on it. I installed R simply with:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

And when I call `$ R` in console, it starts up with:

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) -- "Someone to Lean On"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
...
```

I'd like to get R 3.6 installed, primarily because I need `BiocManager` and a bunch of latest versions of other R packages obtained through `BiocManager`. I've followed the steps [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html), so now my `/etc/apt/sources.list/` looks like (just the bottom bit that's relevant):

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/
# deb-src https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/

deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty-cran35/
# deb-src https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/
```

And ran `sudo apt-get install r-base` again.

But when I run `$ R` from the console again, I still see:

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) -- "Someone to Lean On"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
...
```

Is there something I'm missing? I'm new to setting up R and Linux in general, so I sense that there's a bunch of literature I'm missing about what's available via `apt-get`, R versioning for Ubuntu, and so on. Any links to useful man pages would also be very helpful.

**Edit**: Following the comments:

Ran:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

To no new effect; callnig `R` from console still brings up R v3.4.4.

`apt-cache policy r-base` shows:

```
r-base:
  Installed: 3.4.4-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 3.4.4-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 3.4.4-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Which I assume means R v3.6 isn't even being installed at all?

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update` before trying to install the latest version? What does `apt-cache policy r-base` show?

Comment: Also, you need to remove the `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty-cran35/` line; you've already added the correct (bionic) line.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem and I found this tutorial:
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-18-04/ It solved my problem, hope it helps you!

Answer (score 7):

According to https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html
you should add (considering you are using 18.04, bionic)

```
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/
```

to your

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

after that

```
sudo apt update
```

and

```
sudo apt install r-base
```

Comment: You'll also need to receive the cryptographic key for the server before you're able to install stuff from it.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately i can not comment on the answer of AndreyIto.

For me it has to be `xenial-cran35` instead of `disco-cran35`

So:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/'
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
sudo apt update
sudo apt install r-base
```

For Details and other Ubuntu Versions see [cran.r-project.org](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/):

Comment: Only fully correct answer in this thread.

Comment: The important part is finding your distro with `lsb_release -a` then visiting the cran link and adding the right string.

Answer (score 5):

I successfully installed R 3.6.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.3 following this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu disco-cran35/'
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
sudo apt update
sudo apt install r-base
```

Comment: Shouldn't the key be added _first_, not after add-apt-repository?

Comment: It is not possible to install R from that PPA on Ubuntu 18.04. The R version it broadcasts depends on libc6 2.29, whereas only 2.27 is available for this Ubuntu release.

Answer (score 1):

try

```bsh
echo deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list

sudo apt update

sudo apt install r-base

R --version
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Your answer could benefit from some explanation on why these steps help solve the problem, as the possible audience is not only the OP but other people with possibly less experience in system administration.